# Insert contacts in Android with delphi

Tags: android, delphi, contacts

I have seen that there are many examples to write contacts in Android but not with delphi. 
I tried copying and translating this code, but without success. 
Do any of you have any suggestions of how to enter a simple contact with a couple of numbers and an email in Android with delphi? 
That would be great also understand how to access contacts and their photos. 
Thank you.

Comment: What version of Firemonkey?

Comment: A very simple search for "firemonkey android contacts" showed me this: http://www.fmxexpress.com/tag/contacts/

Comment: Delphi XE7, and all example are for reading, i really need to add :)

Comment: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=109833

Comment: Thanks! I tried for a week and I had missed it I try immediately.

Answer (score 0):

1.(Delphi 10) Try **TAddressBook**. You can look at sample project at c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\Address Book\Contacts\Contacts_Delphi.dproj

In procedure TForm1.FillContactList(Source: TAddressBookSource);
Replace AddressBook1.AllContacts(Source, Contacts);  to
 AddressBook1.AllContacts(**nil**, Contacts); to get all contacts.

You can look at sources of TAddressBook here: \source\fmx\FMX.AddressBook.Android.pas

2.Here are examples on how to Insert, Delete and Update contact for earlier versions of Delphi. based on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578823/Android-Contact-Operations-Insert-Search-Delete.

```
procedure TContactsManager.InsertToContacts(const displayName, firstName, lastName,  phone, eMail: string);
var
  ops: JArrayList;
  res: TJavaObjectArray<JContentProviderResult>;
  rawContactInsertIndex: integer;

const
  DATA_MIMETYPE    = 'mimetype';
  COMMON_DATA_TYPE = 'data2';

begin
  ops := TJArrayList.JavaClass.init;
  rawContactInsertIndex := ops.size;

  ops.add
  (
    TJContentProviderOperation.JavaClass.newInsert
      (
        TJContactsContract_RawContacts.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI
      ).withValue
        (
          TJSyncStateContract_Columns.JavaClass.ACCOUNT_TYPE, nil
        ).withValue
          (
            TJSyncStateContract_Columns.JavaClass.ACCOUNT_NAME, nil
          ).build
  );
     // name
  ops.add
  (
    TJContentProviderOperation.JavaClass.newInsert
      (
        TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI
      ).withValueBackReference
        (
          TJContacts_Entity.JavaClass.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
          rawContactInsertIndex
        ).withValue
          (
            StringToJString(DATA_MIMETYPE),
            TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
          ).withValue
          (
            TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.DISPLAY_NAME,
            StringToJString(displayName)
          ).withValue
          (
            TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.FAMILY_NAME,
            StringToJString(lastName)
          ).withValue
          (
            TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.GIVEN_NAME,
            StringToJString(firstName)
          ).build
      );
    // phone
  ops.add
    (
      TJContentProviderOperation.JavaClass.newInsert
        (
          TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI
        ).withValueBackReference
        (
          TJContacts_Entity.JavaClass.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
          rawContactInsertIndex
        ).withValue
        (
          StringToJString(DATA_MIMETYPE),
          TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
        ).withValue
        (
          TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.NUMBER,
          StringToJString(phone)
        ).withValue
        (
          StringToJString(COMMON_DATA_TYPE),
          StringToJString(IntToStr(TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.TYPE_MOBILE))
        ).build
    );
     // E-Mail
  ops.add
    (
      TJContentProviderOperation.JavaClass.newInsert
        (
          TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI
        ).withValueBackReference
        (
          TJContacts_Entity.JavaClass.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
          rawContactInsertIndex
        ).withValue
        (
          StringToJString(DATA_MIMETYPE),
          TJCommonDataKinds_Email.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
        ).withValue
        (
          TJCommonDataKinds_Email.JavaClass.ADDRESS,
          StringToJString(eMail)
        ).withValue
        (
          StringToJString(COMMON_DATA_TYPE),
          StringToJString(IntToStr(TJCommonDataKinds_Email.JavaClass.TYPE_WORK))
        ).build
    );

  try
    res := SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver.applyBatch(TJContactsContract.JavaClass.AUTHORITY, ops);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;


procedure TContactsManager.DeleteContact(const aLookupID: string);
var
  wDataUri: JNet_URI;

begin
  wDataUri := TJNet_URI.JavaClass.withAppendedPath
    (
     TJContactsContract_Contacts.JavaClass.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,
     StringToJString(aLookupID)
    );

   try
     TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.delete(wDataUri, nil, nil);
   except
     on E: Exception do
       ShowMessage('getContentResolver Delete error: ' + E.Message);
   end;
end;



procedure TContactsManager.UpdateContact(const aLookupID, aPhoneNumber,
  aDislpayName, aFirstName, aLastName, aEmail: string);
var
  ops: JArrayList;
  wJDislpayName,
  wJFirstName,
  wJLastName,
  wJPhone,
  wJEmail,
  wJQueryStr: JString;
  wJQueryParams: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;

  wSubCursor: JCursor;
  wfilter: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  wDataUri: JNet_URI;

begin
  if Trim(aLookupID) = '' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Contact ID is null!!!');
    Exit;
  end;

  wJQueryStr := StringToJString('mimetype = ? AND lookup = ?');
  wDataUri := TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI;

  // Names

  wfilter := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(3);
  wfilter[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.DISPLAY_NAME;
  wfilter[1] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.FAMILY_NAME;
  wfilter[2] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.GIVEN_NAME;

  wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
  wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
  wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(aLookupID);

  with SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver do
    wSubCursor := Query(wDataUri, wfilter, wJQueryStr, wJQueryParams, nil);
  try
    if wSubCursor.getCount > 0 then
    begin
      // Getting only first row, as we retrieving only names, a contact can have only one first name, one familyname,
      // for phone number for example, we need to loop on each row (while (wSubCursor.moveToNext) do) because a contact can have many phone number
      wSubCursor.moveToNext;
      wJDislpayName := wSubCursor.getString(0);
      wJLastName    := wSubCursor.getString(1);
      wJFirstName   := wSubCursor.getString(2);
    end;
  finally
    wSubCursor.close;
    wSubCursor := nil;
  end;

  if Trim(aDislpayName) <> '' then
    wJDislpayName := StringToJString(Trim(aDislpayName));

  if Trim(aFirstName) <> '' then
    wJFirstName := StringToJString(Trim(aFirstName));

  if Trim(aLastName) <> '' then
    wJLastName := StringToJString(Trim(aLastName));

  ops := TJArrayList.JavaClass.init;

  wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
  wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
  wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(aLookupID);

  ops.add
    (
      TJContentProviderOperation.JavaClass.newUpdate
      (
        TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI
      ).withSelection
      (
        wJQueryStr, wJQueryParams
      ).withValue
      (
        TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.DISPLAY_NAME,
        wJDislpayName
      ).withValue
      (
        TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.GIVEN_NAME,
        wJFirstName
      ).withValue
      (
        TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.FAMILY_NAME,
        wJLastName
      ).build
    );

  // Phone

  wfilter := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  wfilter[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.NUMBER;

  wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
  wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
  wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(aLookupID);

  with SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver do
    wSubCursor := Query(wDataUri, wfilter, wJQueryStr, wJQueryParams, nil);
  try
    if wSubCursor.getCount > 0 then
    begin
      // Getting only first phone number , a contact can have multiple phone numbers, so if needed,
      // we need to loop on each row (while (wSubCursor.moveToNext) do)
      wSubCursor.moveToNext;
      wJPhone := wSubCursor.getString(0);
    end;
  finally
    wSubCursor.close;
    wSubCursor := nil;
  end;

  if Trim(aPhoneNumber) <> '' then
  begin
    wJPhone := StringToJString(Trim(aPhoneNumber));

    wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
    wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(aLookupID);

    ops.add
      (
        TJContentProviderOperation.JavaClass.newUpdate
        (
          TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI
        ).withSelection
        (
          wJQueryStr, wJQueryParams
        ).withValue
        (
          TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.NUMBER,
          wJPhone
        ).build
      );
  end;

  // E-Mail

  wfilter := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  wfilter[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Email.JavaClass.ADDRESS;

  wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
  wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Email.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
  wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(aLookupID);

  with SharedActivity.getContentResolver do
    wSubCursor := Query(wDataUri, wfilter, wJQueryStr, wJQueryParams, nil);
  Try
    if wSubCursor.getCount > 0 then
    begin
      // Getting only first email , a contact can have many emails, so if needed,
      // we need to loop on each row (while (wSubCursor.moveToNext) do)
      wSubCursor.moveToNext;
      wJEmail := wSubCursor.getString(0);
    end;
  Finally
    wSubCursor.close;
    wSubCursor := nil;
  End;

  if Trim(aEmail) <> '' then
  begin
    wJEmail := StringToJString(Trim(aEmail));

    wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
    wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Email.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(aLookupID);

    ops.add
      (
        TJContentProviderOperation.JavaClass.newUpdate
        (
          TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI
        ).withSelection
        (
          wJQueryStr, wJQueryParams
        ).withValue
        (
          TJCommonDataKinds_Email.JavaClass.ADDRESS,
          wJEmail
        ).build
      );
  end;

  if ops.size > 0 then
    try
      SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver.applyBatch(TJContactsContract.JavaClass.AUTHORITY, ops);
//    TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.applyBatch(TJContactsContract.JavaClass.AUTHORITY, ops); // DELPHI DX10
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('getContentResolver ApplyBatch for Update  error: ' + E.Message);
    end;
end;
```